# ZF3 - Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression - Wrong escaping on SQL DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, zend-db, zend-framework3

I'm trying to filter a radius accounting database based on the submitted session start time. The field "acctstartime" is defined as DATETIME in the MySQL database.

This is the working SQL query I'd like to build:

`SELECT * FROM radacct WHERE DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2019-08-10' , '%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY "radacctid" DESC LIMIT 100`

In my ZF3-Controller, I'm building the SQL-query based on the submitted parameters using the Zend\Db abstraction layer. But unforunately the Db layer escapes the %-Signs and produces a SQL-string which is not working:

`SELECT * FROM radacct WHERE DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%%Y-%%m-%%d') = DATE_FORMAT('2019-01-01' , '%%Y-%%m-%%d') AND "acctstarttime" = '2019-01-01' ORDER BY "radacctid" DESC LIMIT 100`

In the file `zend-db/src/Sql/Expression.php` on line 136:

`$expression = str_replace('%', '%%', $this->expression);`

Has anybody a clue how to generate the query above? Or maybe another way to do the same thing? I haven't found any workaround for this type of expression using DATE_TIME.

---

The controller:

```php
class AccountingController extends AbstractRestfulJsonController {
    protected $service;

    public function __construct(RadiusService $service) {
        $this->service = $service;
    }

    public function get($id) {
        return $this->getList();
    }

    public function getList() {
        $viewModel = new JsonModel();

        try {
            $filter = [];
            $paramsRoute = $this->params()->fromRoute();
            $paramsQuery = $this->params()->fromQuery();
            $params = (OBJECT) array_merge($paramsRoute, $paramsQuery);

            if(isset($params->id)) {
                $filter['radacctid'] = (int) $params->id;
            }

            // ...

            if(isset($params->sessionStartTime) && strlen($params->sessionStartTime) > 0) {
                $filter[] = new Expression("DATE_FORMAT(acctstarttime, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('" . $params->sessionStartTime . "' , '%Y-%m-%d')");
            }

            // ...

            $data = $this->service->getAccounting($filter);

            $viewModel->setVariable('state', 'ok');
            $viewModel->setVariable('count', $data['totalItems']);
            $viewModel->setVariable('data', $data['items']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $viewModel->setVariable('state', 'nok');
            $viewModel->setVariable('message', $e->getMessage());
        }

        return $viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: what formatof date has column named `acctstarttime`  ?

Comment: the column is DATEIME in the following format 2018-08-07 04:09:02

Comment: so what about "SUBSTRING(acctstarttime, 1, 10) = '". substr($params->sessionStartTime, 0, 10) . "'" ?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Maybe you want to add this as an answer to the question so i can accept it.

Comment: ok, i added it as answer. thnx   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what about "SUBSTRING(acctstarttime, 1, 10) = '". substr($params->sessionStartTime, 0, 10) . "'" ?

Answer (score 0):

The other way, maybe "cleaner" is writing your own class and override `getExpressionData` method to not escape values. For example:

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression;

    public class NonEscapedExpression extends Expression
    {
        /**
         * @return array
         * @throws Exception\RuntimeException
        */
        public function getExpressionData()
        {
            $parameters = (is_scalar($this->parameters)) ? [$this->parameters] : $this->parameters;
            $parametersCount = count($parameters);

            if ($parametersCount == 0) {
                return [
                    str_ireplace(self::PLACEHOLDER, '', $expression)
                ];
            }
            // assign locally, escaping % signs
            $expression = str_replace(self::PLACEHOLDER, '%s', $expression, $count);
            // test number of replacements without considering same variable begin used many times first, which is
            // faster, if the test fails then resort to regex which are slow and used rarely
            if ($count !== $parametersCount && $parametersCount === preg_match_all('/\:[a-zA-Z0-9_]*/', $expression)) {
                throw new Exception\RuntimeException(
                    'The number of replacements in the expression does not match the number of parameters'
                );
            }
            foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
                list($values[], $types[]) = $this->normalizeArgument($parameter, self::TYPE_VALUE);
            }
            return [[
                $expression,
                $values,
                $types
            ]];
        }
    }
```

But you shuould use it carefully.